# Json xcode get data

Tags: iphone, json, youtube, youtube-api, xcode4.3

I have a json http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ruflixnet/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc
and i want to get id,title and size, but don't now how to do that.

Comment: There are sevral libraries for that depending on which language you are coding in at http://json.org/.

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c is one example.

Comment: DON'T WORK !!! see antonio answer

Comment: i have posted the almost all code and the way to do see my code below

Answer (score 2):

i recommend [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) (look at the Benchmarks)

> A Very High Performance Objective-C JSON Library

Parsing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the SBJSON libraries for example, IVe been using them all time and they are pretty good.

You have a tutorial here:

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Answer (score 1):

download the JSON library and include that in your project than make this following class for your data 
Make NSObject class

ObjectData.h

```
  @interface ObjectData : NSObject {

NSString *id; 
NSString *title;
NSString *size;

  }
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *id;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *title; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *size;
@end
```

ObjectData.M

```
   #import ObjectData.h

  @implementation ObjectData

  @synthesize id; 
  @synthesize title;
  @synthesize size;
  @end
```

Make another DataController Class

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


  @interface DataController : NSObject {

  }

  + (id)staticVersion;
 - (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString;
  end


 #import "DataController.h"
 @implementation DataController
 DataController *theInstance;

  +(id)staticVersion
                            {
if(!theInstance){
    theInstance = [[DataController alloc] init];
}
return theInstance;
   }



   - (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theURLString]];
NSString *fileContent= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  
NSArray *items = (NSArray *) data ;  
return items;
    }

   @end
```

And in View Did load

```
  NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:serverName];

   for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {
id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;

ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
[theObject setid:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
[theObject settitle:[dict objectForKey:@"title"]];  
[theObject setsize:[dict objectForKey:@"size"]];



[resultArray addObject:theObject];
[theObject release];
theObject=nil;
```

At last make preferenc.h file and give the your json data path

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  #define serverName @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ruflixnet/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc"
```

hope this works fine

Answer (score 0):

use SBJson

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *dicRes = [parser objectWithString:stringFromServer error:nil];
```